# Multiple segues and slow down again xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

everyone.
I've got a problem, my app has 3 ViewControllers and it segues from one to another hundreds times. 
User added data -> checked -> added -> checked

After about 50 checks it slows down.

After double clicking home button and closing app totally and starting again it works well

How to solve the problem?

I've found the question here "Multiple segues cause app to slow down" but it isn't clear for me

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you are keeping 50 view controllers in your navigation stack. Do you really need to do this? Did you check your memory usage?

Comment: To build on @Desdenova's answer - do you create a new instance of the CheckedViewController each time, or are you reusing it?  If you have to reuse it, are you cleaning it up before you go back to data?

Comment: Maybe look at using a `UIPageViewController` instead

Comment: No, I just did this way: ctrl+drag from button to checkedVC and from button in checkedVC to addedVC. How to reuse and clean it? Thank you!